# Visualize BoxCast

Tags: unity, physics, matrix, raycasting

Im trying to find a way to visualize, and Edit the Physics2D.BoxCast from the Editor.

I wrote the methods below to visualize the BoxCast, and edit in the editor:

```
public Rect Box;
 private void OnDrawGizmos()
 {
     Gizmos.color = Color.magenta;
     Gizmos.matrix = Matrix4x4.TRS(transform.position + (Vector3) Box.position, transform.rotation, Vector3.one);
     Gizmos.DrawWireCube(Vector2.zero, Box.size);
 }

 private void Update()
 {
     var hits = Physics2D.BoxCastAll(transform.position + (Vector3) Box.position, Box.size,
         transform.eulerAngles.z, Vector2.right, 0, 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Player"));
     foreach (var hit in hits)
         Debug.Log(hit.transform.name);
 }
```

It works fine, but when I edit the object rotation I get this problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtQN3.jpg

I can fix it easily, putting just transform.position, instead of transform.position + (Vector3)Box.Position. But if I do it, i will not be able to edit the Raycast position.

So, how I can solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Box.center` instead of `Box.position`. From the docs for `Rect.position`:

> This is the same as min, except that setting it will move the rectangle rather than resize it.

Both `Physics2D.BoxCastAll` and `Gizmos.DrawWireCube` expect you to provide a center point and a size. Right now, your box-cast is being centered at the minimum of the rectangle. If you use `Box.center` instead, then your gizmos should show the correct rectangle and your box cast should match it.